# Twilio Flex listen for Agent status in a custom plugin (Available, Offline)

Tags: plugins, twilio, status, agent

I'm trying to listen for an action to get the agent status.

Something like this:

flex.Actions.addListener("agentAvailable", (payload) => alert("Triggered after event agentAvailable"));

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`SetActivity` Action](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.18.0/docs/Actions.html#.SetActivity). Invoking the `SetActivity` Action allows you to change a worker's status between their available activities. All actions have a `before` and `after` event, so in this case you should listen for the `afterSetActivity` event. You would then have to inspect the activity to check whether it was the *available* activity and then trigger your alert.

```js
flex.Actions.addListener("afterSetActivity", (payload) => {
  if (payload.activityAvailable) {
    alert("Agent is now available!");
  }
})
```